# Annoying exceptions in Silverlight 4 with async validation (RIA Services)

Tags: c#, silverlight, ria

I've set up a custom validation for my Sivlerlight project. There's a grid, and it makes sure the entry is unique by going off to the server and performing a check in the DomainService.

The property is given the attribute to tell it to use the custom validator, and that validator calls a function in the DomainService called 'IsUserNameUnique'.

Now then, the problem is this: I get an exception and the program died. If I detatch the project, I get three error messages (they all say the same - 'isUserNameUnique' failed validation. Please inspect ValidationErrors on the operation for details). If I click through them, what I see is my grid and the validation message I wanted! So I mean it works... sort of. It just has these exceptions that I don't want my end user to see.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Are you specifying this custom validation as an Attribute for a Viewmodel property? Verify that your binding is created properly (ValidatesOnExceptions, NotifyOnValidationError is set accordingly).

A code example would be helpful too.